# Custom model not being saved

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have 2 class Snippet , Comment . 
 Error : when i try to create a snippet object , comment object is always created with default comment object not the one i specify .

```
s = Snippet()
s.comm.title = "Jello"
s.save()
```

this doesn't work:

```
ss = Snippets.objects.all()[0].comm.title
```

return's "default title" not "Jello".

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    title = models.CharField(
        max_length=100,
        blank=True,
        default='default comment')


class Snippet(models.Model):
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, default='')
    code = models.TextField()
    linenos = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    language = models.CharField(choices=LANGUAGE_CHOICES,
                                default='python',
                                max_length=100)
    style = models.CharField(choices=STYLE_CHOICES,
                             default='friendly',
                             max_length=100)
    comm = Comment()

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.comm.save()
        super(Snippet, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using `models.ForeignKey` for the `comm` field in the `Snippet` model. You can read more about [models.ForeignKey](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#foreignkey) in this link.

So your `Snippet` model should look something like this

```
class Snippet(models.Model):
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, default='')
    code = models.TextField()
    linenos = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    language = models.CharField(choices=LANGUAGE_CHOICES,
                                default='python',
                                max_length=100)
    style = models.CharField(choices=STYLE_CHOICES,
                             default='friendly',
                             max_length=100)
    comm = models.ForeignKey(Comment)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.comm.save()
        super(Snippet, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: i know this can be done using foreignkey but this should also be possible to call save for one model from another .

Comment: @shifu no it shouldn't. It would make absolutely no sense. A model is saved in a database, the only way you can create a relationship between tables is with a foreign key.